# Grid with 6 Squares in Flutter (2x3)

Tags: android, flutter, dart

[image: The Layout]

How can i create this kind of Layout? I failed to do it with 2 Columns and 3 Rows. I want to display 6 Cards or Containters from 1-6 in a Scaffold body. I tried it with this Code and it looks good on my emulator, but on my real phone it creates a space at the bottom. The height is wrong i guess

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(

          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: GridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          children: List.generate(6, (index) {
            return CustomContainer(number: index+1,);
          }),
        ));
}
```

[image: Fail on Mobile]

```
class CustomContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  final int number;
  CustomContainer({@required this.number});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () => print("Hallo, $number wurde geklickt"),
      onDoubleTap: () => print("Hallo, $number wurde geklickt"),
      child: Container(
        child: Card(
          child: Center(child: Text(number.toString())),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set aspect ratio of GridView widget's child. You can calculate it by dividing item's height by its width and you can get those from MediaQuery class. kToolbarHeight is height of the AppBar and statusBarHeight is height of the status bar

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    final double statusBarHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top;
    final double itemHeight =
        (size.height - kToolbarHeight - statusBarHeight) / 4;
    final double itemWidth = size.width / 2;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        childAspectRatio: itemHeight / itemWidth,
        shrinkWrap: false,
        children: List.generate(6, (index) {
          return CustomContainer(
            number: index + 1,
          );
        }),
      ),
   );
}
```

Comment: This does also work on my emulator, but not on my real device. I edited my post with a screenshot from my mobile phone. (Image doesnt show, here is link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVWEW.jpg)

Comment: Can you please add code of your CustomContainer class too?

Comment: Is in the post now

Comment: may i ask why divided with /4 and not with /3 since we have 3 items listed and not 4

Comment: @O.T It is correct that we will have 3 rows, but if we divide it by 3 then aspect ratio will be 1:1 again and we won't achieve anything by that.

Comment: The funny thing is, this works on my phone now but not on my emulator. Like i have the space on my emulator now and not on my phone :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206316/discussion-between-o-t-and-antonio-valentic).

Comment: I thing the easier way would be to get the height of the Scaffold body and divide it with 3. The calculated height can be used as a Container height, which i can list with Columns and Rows. But how do i get the body height from Scaffold? Your formular still create overflow

Comment: Height of Scaffold body should be MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - kToolbarHeight - statusBarHeight

Comment: But how do i get the height of Scaffold body?